# Agreed or agree?

Tags: contractions

I often see the following exchange on Internet forums:

> A: (some proposition)
>
> B: Agreed.

Why "agreed", not "agree"? Is it a contracted form of "have agreed" or the past simple? Is the form "agree" (I agree with you) acceptable too?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you look up **agreed** in the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/agreed), you will see that it is an adjective meaning **accepted**. If a person says an adjective on its own, it can mean something like "I am.." or "It is...". The omission of these words is an example of [conversational deletion](https://learnenglishwithdemi.wordpress.com/2015/07/07/conversational-deletion/).

> Doctor: How are you feeling?
>   Patient: [I am] Hungry!
>
> Parent: How are you getting on with your homework?
>   Child: [It is] Done.

In this case, **agreed** on its own means "It is accepted".

**[agree](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/agree)** is the verb form. If you use a verb on its own, it is an imperative: telling somebody to do something. So, if you simply say **agree**, you are telling the other person to agree with you.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be **it is agreed [upon]** rather than substituting in "accepted"? I think accepted has a different meaning.

Comment: @Element115 Think Of It More Like "It Is agreed [upon] between the two of us that 'X' is the case."

Comment: @Element115:  I was thinking of the meaning **to consider something or someone as satisfactory**. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/accept. **Upon** is not required: check the definitions I provided,

Comment: "Rarely seen such an completed answer! Let's give it more up votes, shall we?" "Agreed" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VAdLE-QqcBY